# C# ( XNA Framework) Virtual Piano - Code compiling but not appearing. Output gives the background I specified and nothing else

Tags: c#, xna, polymorphism

I'm doing a college assignment in XNA to make a virtual piano.
I have 2 classes, Piano ( my base class) and PianoNotes ( mysubclass)

I have values declared in Piano,which are used in PianoNotes ( inheritance )
and override functions that use polymorphism.

However when I call the draw function in my Game1 file ( equivalent of main I believe),
nothing appears.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is my code - Game 1 File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace PianoAttempt1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a piano , using pre-recorded wav files
    /// It will have 88 notes
    /// 
    /// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    // Used to draw sprites (2D bitmaps)
    public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


    // Instance is a STATIC member, meaning that there is only one of them
    // No matter how many instances are created
    public static Game1 Instance;

    public List<Piano> children = new List<Piano>();

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        // Set back buffer resolution  
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 820;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 640;  

        Instance = this;  // Creates an instance of the piano class 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here


        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


        // call a "new" version of piano notes?

        children.Add(new Piano());

        for (int i = 0; i < children.Count(); i++)
        {
            children[i].LoadContent();
        }



    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>


    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    /// 


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)

    {
        //GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green); // This works meaning there is something wrong with the draw function...


        // Start drawing sprites, front to back
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.Opaque);


        // Tell all the objects in the scene to draw themselves
        for (int i = 0; i < children.Count(); i++)
        {
            children[i].Draw(gameTime);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
      }
   }
 }
```

Piano File

```
         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using System.Linq;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
         using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
          namespace PianoAttempt1
   {
           public class Piano   // Base class of all the other classes
{

             protected Texture2D Sprite;  // Piano bitmap 

             protected SoundEffect Sound1; // Oct1NoteC
             protected SoundEffect Sound2;  // Oct1NoteC#
             protected SoundEffect Sound3;  // Oct1NoteD
             protected SoundEffect Sound4;  // Oct1NoteD#
             protected SoundEffect Sound5;  // Oct1NoteE
             protected SoundEffect Sound6;  // Oct1NoteF
             protected SoundEffect Sound7;  // Oct1NoteF#
             protected SoundEffect Sound8;  // Oct1NoteG
             protected SoundEffect Sound9;  // Oct1NoteG#
             protected SoundEffect Sound10; // Oct1NoteA
             protected SoundEffect Sound11; // Oct1NoteA#
             protected SoundEffect Sound12; // Oct1NoteB
             protected SoundEffect Sound13; // Oct2NoteC
             protected SoundEffect Sound14; // Oct2NoteC#
             protected SoundEffect Sound15; // Oct2NoteD
             protected SoundEffect Sound16; // Oct2NoteD#
             protected SoundEffect Sound17; // Oct2NoteE
             protected SoundEffect Sound18; // Oct2NoteF
             protected SoundEffect Sound19; // Oct2NoteF#
             protected SoundEffect Sound20; // Oct2NoteG
             protected SoundEffect Sound21; // Oct2NoteG
             protected SoundEffect Sound22; // Oct2NoteG
             protected SoundEffect Sound23; // Oct2NoteG
             protected SoundEffect Sound24; // Oct2NoteG#
             protected SoundEffect Sound25; // Oct2NoteA
             protected SoundEffect Sound26; // Oct2NoteA#
             protected SoundEffect Sound27; // Oct2NoteB     

    public Vector2 Position;  // Position of the piano sprite
    public Vector2 Look;
    public Vector2 Center;
    public float Rotation;

    public virtual void LoadContent()
    {

    }
    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
    }
    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
    }


}
}
```

Piano Notes File

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

 namespace PianoAttempt1
 {
class PianoNotes : Piano   // Extends Piano , it is a subclass of Piano
{

    public override void LoadContent()
    {

        // Load the  audio files from the content pipeline. No need to include file type 
        //--------------    Piano Bitmap ----------------------------------
        Position.X = 100;
        Position.Y = 5;
        Sprite = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("piano_sample");

        Center.X = Sprite.Width / 2;
        Center.Y = Sprite.Height / 2;
        Rotation = 0;
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        Sound1 = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteC");
        //Sound2 = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteC#"); 
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteD");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteD#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteE");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteF");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteF#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteG");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteG#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteA");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteA#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct1NoteB");
        //------------ Octave 2 -----------------------
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteC"); 
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteC#"); 
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteD");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteD#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteE");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteF");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteF#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteG");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteG#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteA");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteA#");
        //Sound = Game1.Instance.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Oct2NoteB");

        base.LoadContent();

    }


    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {



        base.Update(gameTime);

        // Gets the state of the keyboard , allowing the user to use the keys to play..
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();


        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            Sound1.Play();
        }

    }
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // Draw the piano sprite
        Game1.Instance.spriteBatch.Draw(Sprite, Position, null, Color.SkyBlue, Rotation, Center, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }


 }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Game1.LoadContent() method, you need to change

```
       children.Add(new Piano());
```

to

```
       children.Add(new PianoNote());
```

so that when you go to draw the children in Game1.Draw(), this uses the PianoNote's Draw() implementation, rather than the empty Piano.Draw() base class method.

The children collection type is fine.

As a side note - depending how many items end up in this collection, you might want to consider using an alternative to virtual methods, as they are known to be about 40% slower in execution for Xbox360 deployments.

more @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/04/414820.aspx 
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203912.aspx

Comment: OR he could fill Piano draw function making it draw all the notes. Piano is the controller of PianoNote. Maybe he's gonna add something to Piano's update method later? Encapsulation!!!!!

Comment: Please review his code; the Game1 class currently owns a Piano collection and PianoNote derives 
from the Piano class - how can the Piano class 'draw all the notes' when it is not aware of all 
the notes? Currently only the Game1 class does. He's simply just put the base class instance in to 
the children.Add() method rather than the concrete class.

Comment: @Shingesu: I should note its probably not ideal but it looks like he's just prototyping and get something working, what im trying todo is get his code to work. And also point out theres probably better ways (which u might have better ideas about)

Comment: hum, I didn't read all of it. But technically (if he IS following OO standards) it should be that way... I think he's dangled up in "is a/has a", but I'm too lazy to write a full answer explaining all that. Not really linked to the question either. You might add a side note saying that's how it would generally be

Comment: I can see how the heap of SoundEffect class level variables in the Piano class may look as though theyre being used, but they dont have their content loaded until the PianoNote implementation sets them (only one soundeffect too). Perhaps the SoundEffects could be encapsulated by a PianoNote (since I assume there are a limited amount of notes) or perhaps something more generic. But you're right, we're getting into oo principles which is beside the main point of my answer; just getting his code working. Please in future don't mark down answers to source code you havn't completely understood yet.

Comment: I'll be happy to unmark, but you gotta edit it XD. Also the OP complains that the graphics don't show up. Btw, there's no point writing in C# if you're not into OO, he might as well write in C++.NET, faster execution

Comment: Edit what exactly? Much of this confusion is from you not reading the question & code properly. My answer should make the code he has written work. And my side note about performance on the 360 is valid and not supposed to be a complete solution. I don't think it's right marking somebody down for attempting to add value to an answer.

Comment: Just make an edit, the system disallows modifying vote after an hour of making it...

Comment: Just made an edit. Sorry - I thought you meant edit my answer for a different reason :).